# ld: symbol(s) not found... (NewSpeechChannel)

Tags: c, macos, macos-carbon

I can't understand why this happens:

```
"_NewSpeechChannel", referenced from:
_main in ccOIJZkQ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The simple code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp, char **apple) {

  SpeechChannel speechchannel;
  NewSpeechChannel( NULL, &speechchannel );

}
```

Compilation steps:

> Using built-in specs.
>
> Target: i686-apple-darwin10
>    Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~6/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
>
> Thread model: posix
>
> gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
>
> /usr/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/cc1 -quiet -v -imultilib x86_64 -D_*DYNAMIC*_ first.c -fPIC -quiet -dumpbase first.c -mmacosx-version-min=10.6.8 -m64 -mtune=core2 -auxbase first -version -o /var/folders/HQ/HQEeBRxZFdOTLnWFF1cxDU+++TI/-Tmp-//ccyQukF0.s
>
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/../../../../i686-apple-darwin10/include"
>
> #include "..." search starts here:
>
> #include <...>  search starts here:
>
> /usr/local/include
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include
>
> /usr/include
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
>
> /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
>
> End of search list.
>
> GNU C version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3) (i686-apple-darwin10)
>
> compiled by GNU C version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3).
>
> GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=150 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
>
> Compiler executable checksum: fdbb4a71861779b5591b0cf47736cbe7
>
> /usr/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as -arch x86_64 -force_cpusubtype_ALL -o /var/folders/HQ/HQEeBRxZFdOTLnWFF1cxDU+++TI/-Tmp-//ccRRVBTR.o /var/folders/HQ/HQEeBRxZFdOTLnWFF1cxDU+++TI/-Tmp-//ccyQukF0.s
>
> /usr/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/collect2 -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.6.8 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o a.out -lcrt1.10.6.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/x86_64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/x86_64 -L/usr/lib/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/../../../i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/../../.. /var/folders/HQ/HQEeBRxZFdOTLnWFF1cxDU+++TI/-Tmp-//ccRRVBTR.o -lSystem -lgcc -lSystem
>
> Undefined symbols:
>
> "_NewSpeechChannel", referenced from:
>
> > _main in ccRRVBTR.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

which I got by using **gcc -v**

Comment: You didn't link a library you needed to link.  Show your link step.

Comment: The library (or the object file) having the implementation of function `NewSpeechChannel` is not in the `PATH`. Show the compilation steps by adding a `-v` flag to the compile line.

Comment: I added the compilation steps.